# How to set the data retrieved from the SQL server in Kotlin?

Tags: sql-server, kotlin

I would like to retrieve the total value of "eAmount" after grouping them based on current month. However, when I tried to use the rs.getDouble() method for both "eAmount" and "SUM(eAmount)". It says invalid column name of "eAmount". However, I have checked that the column name exists in the table. When I use debug mention, it seems that I am not getting any value back. May I know how do I retrieve the data? Below are my codes:

```
private fun totalSpent()
{
    val sqlCon = SQLCon()
    val current = LocalDateTime.now()
    val month = current.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
    connection = sqlCon.connectionClass()!!
    var cUser : String? = intent.getStringExtra("Current User")
    if (connection == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to make connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
        try {
            val sql =
                "SELECT SUM(eAmount) from Expenses where Username = '$cUser'AND eMonth = '$month' GROUP BY eMonth"
            statement = connection!!.createStatement()
            var rs : ResultSet = statement!!.executeQuery(sql)

            while (rs.next())
            {
               var amount : Double = rs.getDouble("SUM(eAmount)")
                Toast.makeText(this, amount.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            rs.close()
            statement!!.close()

            //Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        } catch (e: Exception) { Log.e("Error", e.message!!) }

    }

}
```

Comment: add a column alias to the `sum()` expression. Like `SELECT SUM(eAmount) AS SumEMount from . . ` and use the alias in  `rs.getDouble("SumEMount")`

Comment: `getDouble` has overloads [`getDouble(columnIndex: Int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/sql/ResultSet#getDouble(kotlin.Int)) and [`getDouble(columnLabel: String!)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/sql/ResultSet#getDouble(kotlin.String)), so in addition to giving the column a name you could also have used a column index of 1. Giving the column a name is by far the much better option, though.